# Prove the group of rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ about origin is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

I am self-studying group theory through the text 'Algebra and Geometry' by A.F.Beardon. I am struggling at a problem which states:

> Show that a finite group of rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ about the origin is a cyclic group. Construct a proper subgroup of the group of rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ about the origin that is not cyclic

So my questions are :

1. What is meant by a finite group of rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ about origin?
2. How to decide which rotation group is non-cyclic?
3. How to solve this problem?

Comment: 1. It means a finite subgroup of the group of rotations. 2. Since finite subgroups won't work, try an infinite subgroup. 3. Think about the rotation with the smallest angle.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is any irrational number, then the group of rotations about an angle $q\alpha\pi$, where $q$ is rational, form a non-cyclic group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the non-cyclic case take the group $G$ generated by a rotation of $1$ radian. Then all elements of this group are of the form $e^{in}$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$and since $\pi$ is irrational there is no $n$ such that $e^{in}=e^{i2\pi k}$. Therefore, $G$ is acyclic.

Comment: Huh? $G$ is just infinite cyclic in this case - you specifically called it the group generated by a rotation of 1 radian, i.e. $G$ is cyclic by definition. Have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @AlexWertheim You are right. I used the wrong terminology. What I meant was that it is non-periodic.

Comment: @Rescy_ Were you looking for non-periodic or non-cyclic? I think I misunderstood.

Comment: @Rescy_ Your question looks like it comes out of the book so I doubt you meant aperiodic. I tried to delete this answer but I can't because you accepted it. This answer is incorrect. What I have described is a non-periodic group, not a non-cyclic one.

Answer (score 1):

As @Qiaochu Yuan said :

1) It means a finite subgroup of the group $$R:=\Big\{r_\theta=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix};\theta\in\mathbb{R}\Big\}$$ which is itself a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R}),$

2) For example, $R$ is uncountable and so it is non-cyclic (each cyclic group is countable because you have the surjective morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to<g>$ defined by $n\mapsto g^n$),

3) Let $G=\{Id=r_0,r_{\theta_1},...,r_{\theta_n}\}$ and $\theta:=\min(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)\in]-\pi,\pi[,$ and show that $G=<r_\theta>.$ Let $r_{\theta'}\in G\backslash\{r_0\}.$ We can suppose that $\theta'\in]0,\pi[$ (replacing $r_{\theta'}$ with $r_{\theta'}^{-1}=r_{-\theta'}$). By definition, $\theta\leq \theta'.$ Let $q$ be the smaller integer such as $\theta'\geq q\theta$ and $\theta'<(q+1)\theta.$ Let $\alpha:=\theta'-q\theta,$ it is the angle of $r_{\theta'}\circ r_\theta^{-q}\in G$ and by minimality of $\theta$ you get $\alpha=0.$ So $r_{\theta'}=r_\theta^q$ and you get $G=<r_\theta>.$

Comment: Could you give a complete solution? I am unexperiencd and am really stuck with problem. The book has no solution manual, so it is impossible for me to check.

Comment: To question 3) ?

Comment: Yeah I find it difficult to obtain an infinite order subgroup of group of rotations which is non-cyclic.

Comment: I tried to write something.

Comment: consider a group generated by two rotations that are mutually irrational, say, 1 radian and $\sqrt{2}$ radian.

Comment: It won't be finite ; here I suppose my group finite (which allows me to write $r_{\theta_1},...,r_{\theta_n}$ as the elements of $G$).

Comment: @Niko : What was your problem exactly ?

Comment: among your $\theta_1,\theta_2,...,\theta_n$ is $A$ that I propose

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a finite subgroup of rotations then
there must be an element 
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos A&-\sin A\\
\sin A&\cos A
\end{array}\right)
\in G$ 
with $A$ as the minimal angle on the range $[0,\pi]$ and among the finite elements of $G$.

One can use this element to generate all of $G$.