# Proving that a finite rotational group in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

G is a finite set of rotations about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, closed under composition. I believe I can prove that G forms an abelian group under composition, but how could I go about proving that G is cyclic?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515203/prove-the-group-of-rotations-of-mathbb-r2-about-origin-is-cyclic

Comment: Thank you for pointing that thread out - it contains a possible solution to my question (written by Balloon), but I'm having trouble understanding part of it. It states that "by the minimality of theta you find alpha=0, which I don't quite follow. The rest of the explanation seems perfectly sound to me though, so I'd appreciate any help in understanding that stage of the reasoning.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Noted, sorry for the poor phrasing, I'll change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder upon division of $\theta '$ by $\theta$ is $\alpha$.  So $\theta '=q\theta +\alpha$, where $\alpha\lt\theta $, by the division algorithm.   But $\alpha\in G$ and $\alpha\lt\theta\implies \alpha=0$, by minimality of $\theta$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it the case that $\alpha \in G$ because $\theta ' - q\theta = \alpha$, and due to closure $\alpha$ is in G? If so, thank you - this makes it much clearer.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that a finite group of rotations is cyclic.   The finite groups of rotations that preserve an icosahedron is not even solvable.  (It's isomorphic to $A_5$.)

Possibly you should focus on proving that a finite group of rotations *in the plane* is cyclic.

Comment: Sorry for the misstatement, the title should have said rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'll change the title now.